# How to install dependent nodes for remotely deployed node-red flows.

Tags: node-red

I am trying to design a Jenkins job to deploy Node-RED flows from test to stage and eventually to prod environments. If I install a new node in the palette manager in the test environment and then through Jenkins copy the flow to a stage environment, is there a way, via command line or any other construct, to have all dependent nodes not yet installed on the stage server installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Node-RED user directory (usually `~/.node-red`) there should be a generated `package.json` file that should contain the list of nodes installed via the pallet manager.

If you copy this over as well and run `npm install` in the user directory it should install all the added nodes

Comment: Yep figured it this morning. Seems I was running a previous version of node-red that didn't have the central package.json file. Upgraded to latest version and everything was smooth sailing after that. Thanks for answering.